# Removing newlines in PHP - but they still show in LONGTEXT in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, validation, longtext

Ello chaps.

Ok - cleaning my string like this:

```
$clean_string = preg_replace("/[\n\r]/"," ",trim($dirty_string));
```

.. Echo it out to the screen and it works - one lovely big lump of text with no newlines.

INSERT it into a LONGTEXT type field in MySQL - then preview the resulting data in Sequel Pro - and for some reason it has new lines. Loads of them, just like it did when it was new, before I cleaned it.

What am I doing wrong? Is it LONGTEXT?

---

This is what the html source looks like when I use the content of a SO page as a the string - note the many spaces and newlines - even when cleaned!

```
    mysql - Trouble with CONCAT and Longtext - Stack Overflow





































                Stack Exchange
```

Comment: May be you still see old records. Are you sure that the table is empty before the insert?

Comment: When you say "echo it out to the screen", are you referring to a browser window? If so, are there any linebreaks in the HTML source?

Comment: @Ivan - nope, refreshed and fresh inserts.

Comment: @lonesomeday - Looked at the source, no line breaks but lots of spaces - could this be an invisible line break character that's NOT \n or \r ?

Comment: @evilswan I can exclude the type of the column, so it's a bug in your code, at the moment I can image 2 possibilities: you clean the string but you insert the dirty one, or you fail with the regexp: use the str_replace of "mfonda"

Comment: Did you check if your query even succeeded? `mysql_query()` returns false if the query failed. If it looks like the DB's not changing between updates, then check if the updates are even happening.

Comment: @Marc these are new rows and do succeed. Thanks for the idea though.

Comment: Added a copy/paste of the resulting HTML output so you can see all the newlines still there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved by using this:

```
$clean_str = str_replace(array("\r", "\n"), '', $dirty_string);
```

BUT - replacing double quotes for single quotes. Works now.

```
$clean_str = str_replace(array('\r', '\n'), '', $dirty_string);
```

Thanks **mfonda** for getting me close!

Answer (score 1):

That should work. Also there really isn't any need to use preg_replace here-- `$clean_str = str_replace(array("\r", "\n"), '', $dirty_string)` will work just fine, and will be a little faster.

Comment: Resulting string when previewed in Sequel Pro still has newlines.

Answer (score 0):

`$clean_string = preg_replace('/\s+/m', ' ',trim($string));` will replace every "space sequence" into a single space. Try it and see if it works as expected.

Comment: Resulting string when previewed in Sequel Pro still has newlines. :( Could it be 'tab' characters that are being shown!?

Comment: /s+ covers all space characters, including tabs. Maybe you're not actually inserting the correct string into your database, or an issue in the viewing program?

Answer (score 0):

How about trimming AFTER removing all newlines?

```
$clean_str = trim(str_replace(array("\r", "\n"), '', $dirty_string));
```